# Adding markers to Google Maps in a loop doesn't work

Tags: google-maps, for-loop

I'm trying to load several random markers to a Google Map. When I run the following script it only produces a single marker which is referenced in the map init function. I'm totally stumped. The non-area is after the declaration of the addMarker function. I know the loop is running via console.log but it's not placing markers on the map.

```
var map;
var northeast;
var southeast;
var northwest;
var southwest;
var markers = [];
var lat = (Math.random() * (80 - -80) + -80).toFixed(7) * 1;
var lng = (Math.random() * (170 - -170) + -170).toFixed(7) * 1;

function initMap() {  
  var randomMarker = {lat: lat, lng: lng}; 

 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 2,
    center: {lat: 0, lng: 0},
    mapTypeId: 'terrain',
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    zoomControl: false,
    scrollwheel: false,
    draggable: false
  }); 

   // Adds a marker at the center of the map.   
  addMarker(randomMarker);
}

 // Adds a marker to the map and push to the array.
      function addMarker(location) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: location,
          map: map,
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          icon: "https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png",
          scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(22, 22)
        });
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            markers.push(marker);
        }
      }


// Test loop

function testHello() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log("hello world");
  }
}

// Sets the map on all markers in the array.
function setMapOnAll(map) {
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    markers[i].setMap(map);
  }
}

// Checkbox function for Northeast quadrant
$('#neVisible').change(function() {
    // this will contain a reference to the checkbox   
    if (this.checked) {
         setMapOnAll(map);
    } else {
         setMapOnAll(null);
    }
});

// Checkbox function for Southeast quadrant
$('#seVisible').change(function() {
    // this will contain a reference to the checkbox   
    if (this.checked) {
         setMapOnAll(map);
    } else {
         setMapOnAll(null);
    }
});


// Checkbox function for Northwest quadrant
$('#nwVisible').change(function() {
    // this will contain a reference to the checkbox   
    if (this.checked) {
         setMapOnAll(map);
    } else {
         setMapOnAll(null);
    }
});


// Checkbox function for Southwest quadrant
$('#swVisible').change(function() {
    // this will contain a reference to the checkbox   
    if (this.checked) {
         setMapOnAll(map);
    } else {
         setMapOnAll(null);
    }
});
```

Comment: Please add only the relevant part of the code, this way it takes extra effort to go through all of it. It seems that you are adding same marker to the map multiple times, instead of creating new one each time.

Comment: Sorry about that. You are correct, it is adding the same marker multiple times,

Comment: No problem, just a tip for the next time you open a question. Glad I could help. Cheers! :)

Comment: If you could check out my comment at bottom. I still can't get this to work :(.

Answer (score 0):

The `addMarker` function is called just once from `initMap` function.

```
// Adds a marker at the center of the map.   
  addMarker(randomMarker);
```

The `addMarker` function will create only one marker

```
// Adds a marker to the map and push to the array.

 function addMarker(location) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: map,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      icon: "https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png",
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(22, 22)
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        markers.push(marker);
    }
  }
```

The for loop adds the same marker to the markerArray 10 times.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    markers.push(marker);
}
```

Due to this all markers will get plotted on the same point and it will look like you have just one marker on the map. In order to fix the issue you need to call the `addMarker` function multiple times and alter it as follows :

```
function addMarker(location) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    icon: "https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png",
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(22, 22)
  });

  markers.push(marker);
}
```

This will create a new marker and add it to the markers array.
Edit the initMap function to create random coordinates and add markers at those locations. Try zooming out of the map to view all the markers together.

```
function initMap() {  

 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 2,
    center: {lat: 0, lng: 0},
    mapTypeId: 'terrain',
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    zoomControl: false,
    scrollwheel: false,
    draggable: false
  }); 

  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var lat = (Math.random() * (80 - -80) + -80).toFixed(7) * 1;
    var lng = (Math.random() * (170 - -170) + -170).toFixed(7) * 1;
    var randomMarker = {lat: lat, lng: lng}; 

   // Adds a marker at the center of the map.   
   addMarker(randomMarker);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Still can't get it to work. I added both for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) { addMarker(locations); } and for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) { addMarker(); } in the function initMap and no markers appeared. Any additional help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have updated the initMap code in the answer above. Make those changes and try.